# anychart column-3d doesn't correctly display x-axis labels with categorized_by_series=true

Tags: anychart, anychart-8.2

I am wondering is anychart column-3d has a way to fix displaying correct x-axis named while categorizing the series.

I have the following xml:

```
<anychart xmlns="http://anychart.com/schemas/8.0.0/xml-schema.xsd">
<chart type="column-3d" default_series_type="column" y_scale="0" z_angle="30" z_aspect="20" categorized_by_series="true">
    <margin top="40">
    </margin>
    <chart_labels>
        <label text="Bericht Gesamt||export.aspx?questionGroupId=38&amp;version=2" anchor="top" position="left" enabled="true">
        </label>
        <label text="../anychart.aspx?qg=38&amp;version=2" anchor="top" position="left" enabled="true">
        </label>
    </chart_labels>
    <title enabled="true" use_html="true">
        <text><![CDATA[Report für ELBI International S.p.A., GT Gerätefertigung (DE), 20200101 - 20210114, Lieferantenqualifizierung<br><div style="color:#0000FF; font-size: 10px;border: solid 1px #000;">Lieferantenqualifizierung, Erfüllung in % : 86,19 (AB)</span>]]></text>
    </title>
<y_grids>
  <grid>
    <palette>
      <items>
        <item color="#CCC" opacity="0.25"/>
        <item color="#FFF"/>
      </items>
    </palette>
  </grid>
</y_grids>
<y_axes>
        <axis>
    <title use_html="true">
      <text><![CDATA[<b>Set axis name here</b>]]></text>
    </title>
            <minor_ticks enabled="true"/>
        </axis>
    </y_axes>
<scales>
        <scale type="linear" minimum="0" maximum="100">
            <ticks interval="10" />
            <minor_ticks interval="2" />
        </scale>
    </scales>
    <series_list>
        <series name="Qualität">
            <tooltip enabled="true">
                <format><![CDATA[Erfüllung in %: {%percentReached} ({%rating}) \nPunkte: {%score}]]></format>
      <title>Qualität</title>
            </tooltip>
            <data>
                <point value="81.9" percentReached="81,90" actionType="updateChart" sourceMode="externalData" rating="AB" score="40,95" x="1" source="../anychart.aspx?qg=39&amp;version=2">
                </point>
            </data>
        </series>
    <series name="Lieferung">
            <tooltip enabled="true">
                <format><![CDATA[Erfüllung in %: {%percentReached} ({%rating}) \nPunkte: {%score}]]></format>
      <title>Lieferung</title>
            </tooltip>
            <data>
                <point value="90.48" percentReached="90,48" actionType="updateChart" sourceMode="externalData" rating="A " score="45,24" x="1" source="../anychart.aspx?qg=41&amp;version=2">
                </point>
            </data>
        </series>
    </series_list>
</chart>
```

In 3d mode it shows x-labels from point's x value directly and looks like this:
[image]

But switching back to simple column type fix the issues:
[image]

Maybe someone knows a way around to overcome this?
This is the last chart version 8.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks goes to anychart support.
Unfortunatly, 3d charts doesn't support categorized_by_series attribute, at least for now.
If you need this functionality, you have to used 2d variant only.